# How to select cross multiple lines in regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

How could I select and replace something like below:

```
"
sfg sdgfghsdf dgfdg PAGE 1
sdgffd
fdgfd
sfdgf
*cloum 1 *cloum 2 *cloum 3 *cloum 4 *cloum 5 *
*cloum 6 *cloum 7 *cloum 8 *cloum 9 *cloum 0 *

This is what I want

"
sfg sdgfghsdf dgfdg PAGE 1
sdgffd
fdgfd
sfdgf
*cloum 1 *cloum 2 *cloum 3 *cloum 4 *cloum 5 *
*cloum 6 *cloum 7 *cloum 8 *cloum 9 *cloum 0 *

And This is also what I want
```

It's a pattern. I have to delete all those lines (between " and  cloum 0 *) in notepad++. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Find what:**

```
(?s)".*?cloum 0 \*
```

`(?s)` [DOTALL modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) which makes dots in your regex to match even also the newline characters. `*` is a special character in regex which repeats the previous token zero or more times. So you need to escape the `*` to match a literal `*`

*OR*

```
"[\S\s]*?cloum 0 \*
```

**Replace with:**

```
empty string
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jI2rD0/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But what does (?s) mean?

Comment: by default `.` in the regex won't match line breaks. In-order to make dot to match also the line-creaks, you need to add dotall `s` modifier.